# React Nodemailer Express API not connecting to backend

Tags: reactjs, express, nodemailer

Localhost:
On localhost:3000 and express server running on localhost:5000 my nodemailer sends the email.

Production.
I have installed Node & NPM on my hostinger shared account and created a folder outside the public_html directory for my express server, when I run pm2 start server.js --watch the server starts.

For testing purposes when I redirect my IP to 153.xx.x.xxx:5000 within htaccess my server shows that its running.

When I try to submit my contact form using my API via postman or production I get a timeout error.

> Form.jsx:67 POST https://153.xx.x.xxx:5000/api/send
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Check firewall(s)